# How do i use sed in a loop?

Tags: bash

I am trying to use a script to loop though a rawlist and then remove some words (lines) and put it into a final list.

```
#! /bin/sh

while read p; do
  sed -e "s/$p//g" domains > finaldomains
done <exclude
```

This is what the files contain:

**rawlist:** 
test 
test2
exclude
exclude2

**excludewords:**
exclude
exclude2

Comment: Each time through the loop you're processing the original file, not the result of the previous iteration. So you're not accumulating all the changes. The final result is just the last replacement.

Comment: Is `rawlist` supposed to be `domains`, and `excludewords` should be `exclude`?

Answer (score 0):

```
...
done <exclude
```

`exclude` maybe a file that have exclude words ..?
i changed file name. `exclude` -> `excludes.txt`

---

- you used `>`. so in the loop, each `sed` command uses the rawfile and overwrites previous `finaldomains` file. just added sed option `i` then it updates only one `finaldomains` file in loop
- even if each sed command executes correctly, there may be overlapping words like ('**exclude**', '**exclude**2'). so i wrapped $p with `<>` to find exact same row

```
#! /bin/sh

cp domains finaldomains
while read p; do
    echo $p
    sed -i "s/\<$p\>//g" finaldomains
done < excludes.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

For performance reasons, don't use `sed` in a shell loop.
Instead of processing the file *N* times,  you can accomplish this task in a single pass through each file

With awk

```sh
awk '
    NR == FNR {excluded[$0]; next}
    {
        for (word in excluded)
            if ($0 ~ word)
                print
    }
' exclude domains > finaldomains
```

Or grep

```sh
grep -vwFf exclude domains > finaldomains
```

I'm assuming you want to remove *lines* from "domains" when an "exclude" match is made.

Answer (score 0):

Since you were using `sed`, here's another approach - it isn't *better* than the `awk` solutions provided, but sometimes it's nice to add a tool to the box, so to speak.

```
$: sed 's.^./.; s.$./d;.;' exclude>lst && sed -f lst domains > finaldomains && cat finaldomains
test
test2
```

What that does: ``` 's.^./.; s.$./d;.;'`` adds ``` /`to the beginning and`/d;`to the end of each line (make sure there are no unwanted spaces &c...), turning that list *into* a sed script that excludes those lines.`sed -f lst` runs that resulting script file against your input.